# getArguments() is returning null

Tags: java, android, arguments, bundle

I'm having a problem using fragments. Indeed, I'm trying to pass some arguments to a Fragment from my Activity. The problem is that my `getArguments()` call always returns null. Here is my code:

AlbumUser.java :

```
public class AlbumUser extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_album_user);

        String albumId = getIntent().getStringExtra("albumId");
        String albumName = getIntent().getStringExtra("albumName");
        String albumAuthor = getIntent().getStringExtra("albumAuthor");
        String coverUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("coverUrl");

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentAlbum, Album.newInstance(albumId,albumName,albumAuthor,coverUrl)).commit();

    }
}
```

Album.java :

```
public class Album extends Fragment {

    private String albumId;
    private String albumName;
    private String albumAuthor;
    private String coverUrl;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_album, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        albumId = args.getString("albumId");
        albumName = args.getString("albumName");
        albumAuthor = args.getString("albumAuthor");
        coverUrl = args.getString("coverUrl");
        return view;
    )

    public static Album newInstance(final String albumId, final String albumName, final String albumAuthor, final String coverUrl) {
        final Album album = new Album();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("albumId", albumId);
        bundle.putString("albumName", albumName);
        bundle.putString("albumAuthor", albumAuthor);
        bundle.putString("coverUrl", coverUrl);
        album.setArguments(bundle);
        return album;
    }
}
```

activity_album.xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentAlbum"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            class="com.example.jeff.facebookphotocast.Album" />

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Please help me, I'm dying ^^
Thanks :)

Comment: The code you posted seems to be broken; the only call of `getArguments()` I can see is in the `onCreateView` method in the `Album` class, but the value isn't used anywhere. Also, the line beneath has to end with a semicolon. Could you explain, how you're using the result of `getArguments()` in more detail?

Comment: Okay, I edited the code. It's not broken, I just wanted to show the useful parts of the code. The thing I'm trying to do is displaying a Toast from my Fragment with a String I have in my Activity. The Toast is displayed in the onActivityCreated() method. But for some reasons, the Bundle I get in my Fragment is null... Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Is `R.id.fragmentAlbum` a fragment in your layout, without any arguments, and it fails with the problem you've described? And you'd only later be replacing it with a fragment with arguments.

Comment: I posted the code of my activity's layout. So yeah, it's a fragment. Do I have to add some arguments im my fragment tag ?

Answer (score 4):

The layout XML

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentAlbum"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.example.jeff.facebookphotocast.Album" />
```

instantiates your `Album` fragment without any arguments. That's why `getArguments()` returns null.

If you want to always supply some arguments to your fragment, replace this part of the layout with e.g. an empty `FrameLayout` container, and use `FragmentTransaction#add()` to put your fragment-with-args in the container.